# Grails: reusing render calls in controllers

Tags: grails

I am looking for a way to reuse render code shared by multiple controllers. For example, the following render call:

```
render(contentType: "text/json", status: BAD_REQUEST) {
    error(description: 'Missing param')
}
```

Is it possible to share such code between controllers?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can put this into a base class or add some tool/helper class.  Be sure to `return` in any case (last line in groovy is considered a `return` by default).

e.g.

```
def renderBadRequest() { render(contentType: "text/json", status: BAD_REQUEST) { error(description: 'Missing param') } }
```

and call it somewher else:

```
if (somethingswrong) {
    return renderBadRequest()
}
```

Comment: can i render for a helper class? I thought i can render only with controller

Comment: at least by passing down the controller

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract this functionality into a `Filter`:

```
class BadReqRenderingFilters {

  def filters = {
    all( controller:'*', action:'*' ) {
      after = { Map model ->
        if( model.somethingBad ){
          render(contentType: "text/json", status: BAD_REQUEST) { error(description: 'Missing param') }
          return false 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

see http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mixins. One of the advantage over using a `BaseController` is that controllers can have more than one mixin and at the same time extend another one e.g. RestfulController.

Here is an example of a mixin

```
// src/groovy/...
class ControllerResponseMixin{

    protected renderBadRequest(){
        render(contentType: "text/json", status: BAD_REQUEST) {
            error(description: 'Missing param')
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can use in the controllers as follows:

```
// grails-app/controller/...
@Mixin(ControllerResponseMixin)
class SomeController{

        def show(){
            ...
            renderBadRequest()
        }
}
```